# Separate columns for product counts using CTEs

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, aggregate, common-table-expression

Asking a question again as my post did not follow community rules.

I first tried to write a PIVOT statement to get the desired output. However, I am now trying to approach this using CTEs.

Here's the raw data. Let's call it `ProductMaster`:

| PRODUCT_NUM | CO_CD | PROD_CD | MASTER_ID | Date | ROW_NUM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1854 | MAWC | STATIONERY | 10003493039 | 1/1/2021 | 1 |
| 1567 | PREF | PRINTER | 10003493039 | 2/1/2021 | 2 |
| 2151 | MAWC | STATIONERY | 10003497290 | 3/2/2021 | 1 |

I require the Count of each product for every Household from this data in separate columns, Printer_CT, Stationery_Ct

Each Master_ID represents a household. And a household can have multiple products.

So each household represents one row in my final output and I need the Product Counts in separate columns. There can be multiple products in each household, 4 or even more. But I have simplified this example.

I'm writing a query with CTEs to give me the output that I want. In my output, each row is grouped by Master ID

| ORGL_CO_CD | ORGL_PROD_CD | STATIONERY_CT | PRINTER_CT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| MAWC | STATIONERY | 1 | 1 |
| MAWC | STATIONERY | 1 | 0 |

Here's my query. I'm not sure where to introduce Column 'Stationery_Ct'

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT
        CO_CD, Prod_CD, MASTER_ID,
        '' as S1_CT, '' as P1_CT 
    FROM
        ProductMaster
    WHERE
        ROW_NUM = 1
), CTE_2 AS
(
    SELECT Prod_CD, MASTER_ID
    FROM ProductMaster
    WHERE ROW_NUM = 2
)
SELECT 
    CO_CD AS ORGL_CO_CD, 
    c.Prod_CD AS ORGL_PROD_CD,  
    (CASE WHEN c2.Prod_CD = ‘PRINTER’ THEN P1_CT = 1 END) PRINTER_CT
FROM 
    CTE AS c
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    CTE_2 AS c2 ON c.MASTER_ID = c2.MASTER_ID
```

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can solve that using just `GROUP BY` and `SUM`:

```sql
-- Test data
DECLARE @ProductMaster AS TABLE (PRODUCT_NUM INT, CO_CD VARCHAR(30), PROD_CD VARCHAR(30), MASTER_ID BIGINT)
INSERT @ProductMaster VALUES (1854, 'MAWC', 'STATIONERY', 10003493039)
INSERT @ProductMaster VALUES (1567, 'PREF', 'PRINTER', 10003493039)
INSERT @ProductMaster VALUES (2151, 'MAWC', 'STATIONERY', 10003497290)

SELECT
    MASTER_ID,
    SUM(CASE PROD_CD WHEN 'STATIONERY' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS STATIONERY_CT,
    SUM(CASE PROD_CD WHEN 'PRINTER' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS PRINTER_CT
FROM @ProductMaster
GROUP BY MASTER_ID
```

The result is:

| MASTER_ID | STATIONERY_CT | PRINTER_CT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10003493039 | 1 | 1 |
| 10003497290 | 1 | 0 |